# Cygwin: can't change permissions for file

Tags: windows-xp, permissions, cygwin

My OS is Windows XP, Cygwin 2.5.2. After installing the new version, I had to reinstall the old one that works on Windows XP. But now in my .ssh folder I can't change file permissions under any user in the OS:

```
$ ls -la
total 17
drwxr-xr-x+ 1 my_user None    0 Jun 25 16:34 ./
drwxr-xr-x+ 1 my_user None    0 Jun 25 16:40 ../
-rwxr-xr-x+ 1 my_user None  493 Jun 19 02:32 config*
-rwxr-xr-x+ 1 my_user None  668 Mar 19  2011 id_dsa*
-rwxr-xr-x+ 1 my_user None  612 Feb 19  2011 id_dsa.pub*
-rwxr-xr-x+ 1 my_user None 1675 Mar 24  2011 id_rsa*
-rwxr-xr-x+ 1 my_user None  404 Mar 24  2011 id_rsa.pub*
-rwxr-xr-x+ 1 my_user None 3788 Jun 16 01:57 known_hosts*
-rwxr-xr-x+ 1 my_user None 1464 Jul  7  2016 rsa_putty.ppk*
```

I am logged in as `my_user` and tried to run:

```
$ chmod 200 ./id_rsa
chmod: changing permissions of './id_rsa': Permission denied
```

I tried to do the same as Administrator - the same result. Seems, that something broke during the reinstallation of Cygwin. Is it possible to fix?

**Update**

```
$ cacls ./id_rsa
d:\bin\cygwin\home\my_user\.ssh\id_rsa ORGANIZA-R2ODEV\my_user:F
                                      CREATOR OWNER:(OI)(CI)(IO)F
                                      ORGANIZA-R2ODEV\None:R
                                      CREATOR GROUP:(OI)(CI)(IO)R
                                      Everyone:(OI)(CI)R

$ getfacl ./id_rsa
# file: ./id_rsa
# owner: my_user
# group: None
user::rwx
group::r-x
other:r-x
default:user::rwx
default:group::r-x
default:other:r-x
```

Comment: The trailing `+` on the permissions means that there are extended permissions on the file you are trying to change. See [here](https://serverfault.com/a/227858/409801). You will need `getfacl` and `chacl` to resolve this. (This is based on standard Linux: I have assumed that `CygWin` is similar.)

Comment: What is the output of cygwin `id` and of windows `cacls id_rsa` ?

Comment: @matzeri Added the output to the question

Comment: @AFH Please, look at the update.

Comment: OK. It looks as though the trailing `+` is misleading, as there seems to be no ACL. But the mode 0200 is odd: it is very rare to have write-only files, and Windows file systems don't support it, though `CygWin` may have its own permissions overlaying those of Windows. Can you set other permissions, eg 0700 or 0750?

Comment: @AFH `Can you set other permissions, eg 0700 or 0750?` - no, the same error: "Permission denied"

Comment: @AFH It seems weird but after moving .ssh folder out of my cygwin home folder, I changed the permissions successfully. So the issue was not inside the directory, by outside it. What can it be?

Comment: Do you have write permission on `~/.ssh` (run `ls -ld ~/.ssh` to check)? I don't know what else to suggest, but in searching for information on `cygwin chmod` I found lots of error reports. Maybe you have encountered one of those bugs.

Comment: @AFH "Do you have write permission on ~/.ssh (run ls -ld ~/.ssh to check)?" - yes, I have write permissions. Weird bug, upvoted couple of your posts. Thanks.